# Cuda error 30 disappears when I debug in Nsight

Tags: cuda, gpu, nsight

VS 2010k and Nsight v3

I am making mods to some cuda modules;  when I run in Debug mode in VS this Host code:

```
result = cuLaunchKernel ( cuFunction, dimGrid.x, dimGrid.y, dimGrid.z, dimBlock.x, dimBlock.y, dimBlock.z, shared, stream, argsG, 0);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
err = cudaGetLastError();
```

i get value of **result** is zero but **err** is 30 [or Unknown] on the first time thru this part of the code and every time thru.

So I fired up NSight thinking to trap the problem.  Processed my whole input file without any errors.  Turned on memory check in Nsight and reran.  again processed whole file without a complaint.

So:  Under Host debug every launch of this code results in error 30 but running under control of Nsight and no errors.

Anyone have an explanation ?

thanks

Comment: Looks to me like you're mixing driver API (e.g. cuLaunchKernel) and runtime API (e.g. cudaDeviceSynchronize, cudaGetLastError).  Do you see any different results if you use the driver API functions ([cuCtxSynchronize](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/index.html#group__CUDA__CTX_1g7a54725f28d34b8c6299f0c6ca579616) and parse the returned CUresult directly rather than using cudaGetLastError)  ?  Also, you may wish to look at one of the driver API cuda samples for an example of driver API error parsing.

Comment: Thanks for the thought.  But a) code has been working for 5 months this way; b) does not explain why code works fine when running in Nsight; and c) tried it anyway, no change in behavior.  Its not the manner of the synch

Comment: Can you post a reproducible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved thr program issue:  there was a bad global memory address being calculated due to bug.  why Nsight did *not* catch the error but sailed right on thru -- even with memory check turned on i do not understand.